# Can't install Chrome. How can I fix this?

Tags: google-chrome

I think I should begin by saying that I am totally new to Linux and not very computer savvy.

After downloading Google Chrome I got the following error message on the software center:

```
Breaks existing package 'google-chrome-stable:i386' conflict: google-chrome-stable ()
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Is your system 32-bit or 64-bit. `uname -i`?

Comment: Which architecture do you have? If you have amd64 then you'll have to make an i386 one. Then you just install google chrome as you did. and btw... Which distro are you using?

Answer (score 4):

So we're going to use the command line. First, open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, or search the Dash (click the Ubuntu logo) for Terminal. It looks like this:

[image]

Then type the following command into it and press enter:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable:i386
```

you can copy and paste by right clicking or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.

When you press enter, it will ask for your password. When you type it, nothing will show up (not even asterisks) but it is still letting you type it. Press enter when you have typed it, and the command will run, with an output similar to this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  google-chrome-stable
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 111 mB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 339555 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-chrome-stable (2.8-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
```

When it finishes (the last line will look like `username@computername:~$`), you can open the Software Centre and try to install it again. You can also close the terminal.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. And thanks for explaining it in a way I could understand!

Comment: @user3710626 as this solved it please tick the grey check mark below the down arrow to mark as solved!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the existing Google Chrome package:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable:i386
```

That's all -  not more and not less.